# Consulta en mysql con sumatoria sobre un campo

Tags: mysqli

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, tengo una tabla llamada devoluciones y necesito sumar en una consulta las cantidades ya devueltas registradas con anterioridad para cada producto que pertenecen a un valor en común en el campo comp_sal. Necesito sumar todas las cantidades del mismo código de producto, para cada producto, que aparecen en la tabla creo que obtengo un arreglo. Adjunto código de la consulta que me suma todos las unidades de producto sin diferenciar código. ...Yo le agregé un indice pero no funciona ...por favor si alguien puede ayudarme

```
  $sql2 = "SELECT SUM(devoluciones.cantdev) as cantdev, 
                  devoluciones.id_producto as devprod 
           from devoluciones, productos 
           where devoluciones.comp_sal = '$idcomp' 
           and devoluciones.id_producto = productos.id_producto  ";

$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {

    $devprod = $row['devprod'];

    $cantidadev[$devprod] = $cantidadev[$devprod] + $row['cantdev'];

}
```

Comment: Te falta por ejemplo haces `GROUP BY......` de todas las columnas que tienes en tu `SELECT` menos aquella que obtuviste producto de la función de agregación `SUM`

Comment: seria group by  devoluciones.id_producto ?

Comment: Trata así primero desde tu gestor y comenta si desde el gestor con esa modificación obtienes ese resultado deseado

Comment: Si funciona pero es más compleja la pregunta ahora que traigo el array porque necesito ponerlo en una columna de una tabla que posee campos de otras tablas...podrias ayudarme por favor...necesito sacar esto urgente

Comment: Gracias Aprendiz....